# LyX shortcut to go to label

Tags: lyx, shortcut

Right now I can right-click on a cross-reference, then click on "Go to Label".

Is there a quicker way I can do this? (For example, maybe something like Ctrl + Left mouse click.)

It says there "Ctrl + >" but I am having trouble figuring out how that shortcut works.

[image]

Comment: Exactly how the keyboard shortcut works depends on your keyboard layout. For example on my American layout (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#/media/File:LinuxUSKeyboard.png) the key between the left shift and Z has `<` and `>`. To get the `>` I need to hold down Shift. So to use the go to label shortcut, I hold down Ctrl and Shift, then hit the mentioned key. A quick test indicates that the cursor has to be left of the cross-reference, when on the right it doesn't work.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. good explanation. The reason why it only works on the left is because if there is e.g. two references, LyX needs some way to decide on which it should act, so by default it acts on whatever thing is on the right. It might be interesting to introduce functionality such as "well there is no inset on the right, so try the thing on the left", but right  now such smart functionality doesn't exist.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I see now how that shortcut works. But it seems to require that the cursor be directly to the left of the cross-reference, so it's no improvement over Right-Click + click "Go to Label". I wonder if there's something like Alt-Click or Ctrl-Click. If not, I would recommend it; I don't imagine it's too hard to implement.

Comment: I know it only works with the cursor on the left, I said as much. And @scottkosty explained the reason. Also, no point in addressing such a recommendation to me, I'm not a LyX developer, feature requests should be posted on https://www.lyx.org/trac. I don't know if it's possible to configure LyX to use alt-click or similar, but scottkosty might know.

Comment: I don't think it's currently possible to configure custom mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One shortcut is: Right-click, then "g".

Answer (score 3):

(Summarizing comments.)

Exactly how the keyboard shortcut works depends on your keyboard layout. For example on my [American layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#/media/File:LinuxUSKeyboard.png) the key between the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> has <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>. To get the <kbd>></kbd> I need to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>. So to use the go-to-label shortcut, I hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then hit the mentioned key.

Note that the cursor has to be placed on the left side of cross-reference for this to work. As scottkosty says, this is so that it's clear which label to go to, if there are two cross-references side by side.

It is not currently possible to configure a mouse click, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click, to achieve this it seems. You could make a feature request to the developers by creating a new ticket at https://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: It looks like Ctrl+< works to "Go back," but I'm not exactly clear what "Go Back" means.  Does it go back to wherever you were just before this, or does it always go back to some reference linking to the current label?  I still find using grep on the .lyx file at the command line the best way to find all the places where a label is referenced.

Comment: @JosiahYoder In this specific case it looks like go from a cross reference to the label it references, but I have no idea if it can do other things. Have you looked in the documentation? (Help-menu in LyX)